# What is wrong with this code in json and php ... consol error?

Tags: php, html, json

```js
<?php
$myObj->name = "John";
$myObj->age = 30;
$myObj->city = "New York";

$myJSON = json_encode($myObj);

echo $myJSON;
?>
```

I see this from the browser:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0at JSON.parse ()at XMLHttpRequest.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange

```html
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo">change text </p>

<button type="submit" onClick="loaddco()">click me</button>
<script>
function loaddco(){
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj.name;
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "demo_file.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

I see this from the browser:Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0at JSON.parse ()at XMLHttpRequest.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange

Comment: Seems like your server is returning HTML instead of (or as well as) JSON. Do some debugging.

Comment: Look at the response in your browser's developer console Network tab, see what the response from the server actually is